# how can i make a css hover over image Without affecting the image

Tags: hover

see the image ...
To understand ;P

this is the code i use

```
.img1 {
background-image: url('img1.png');
width: 381px;
height: 187px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: left;}

.img1:hover {
    background-image: url('imghover.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 115px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

but it is affecting the img1
I want it to appear above the img1 without affecting on it

i fix it sorry

see this is example 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/css.gif

+
another one

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/css2.gif

Comment: What does 'affecting on it' mean? You are changing the image URL, so it's being affected. Also, since both the images in your link appear to have the same aspect ratio, why have you specified a different height for :hover?

Comment: @Osiris sorry i give the wrong code check it again above ^ with the example

Answer (score 1):

On hover you are setting height as 381px and margin-top as -116px

```
height: 381px;
margin-top: -116px;
```

Which can affect the image 1.

Comment: sorry i give the wrong code check it again above ^ with the example